# Why is \n included when reading files? Python

Tags: python

As the title states: Why is `\n` included when reading files?

I found a lot of information about how to remove it - but no information about why it is there in the first place.

Comment: ... Because it's in the file?

Comment: Because it is a part of the file. And furthermore on a Windows system. The endings are `'\r\n'`, not `'\n'`.

Comment: Take a look at the first table at [Strings and Bytes Literals](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: The question might sound silly written like this, but it is valid to ask why `'\n'` is kept in each string of `list(file)` where we already use the character to split the lines. Below, jberrio provides a fair answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `'\n'` character is read because it exists in the file, simple as that. If there were no line breaks or carriage returns, the text file would render as a single line of text.

For example, if you open a notepad application and see

```
this is a sentence
that wraps over
```

Then that explicitly contains the characters

```
this is a sentence\nthat wraps over
```

Comment: So the \n in the file is in the form of a line break, which in python corresponds to \n?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what others have answered - Python could have been designed to discard it when reading each line.  But then, if you rewrite each line to a new file, you would have to add it; otherwise it would write all the lines it read into a single straight line.

Keeping it (as read from data files) maintains the integrity of the original data and allows you to manipulate it from its original condition.